# A random word generator that has the user type the word to confirm

Tags: python, function, if-statement, while-loop

Source code for a random word generator that has the user type the word to confirm

```py
def word_list(): 
  import random #Import random function
  words = ['hello',"yes","no","I","look","where","can","he","with","see","do","we","a","you","play","am","what","one","the","this","have","on","want","go","like","and","hurt","to","under","day","is","or","of","it","are","said","big","up","that","little","down","there","my","she","out","good","her","all","yes","make","read","no","they","your\n"]
  question = random.choice(list(words)) #Generates a random word from the list
  print(question) #Displays the word that was generated
  answer = input('Retype the word and press enter:') #User retypes the 
  while True: #Loop that allows user to 
    if answer == question: #If statement that confirms the user spelled the word right
      print('Great job you spelled it correctly!')
      input('Press enter for another word')
    else: 
      while answer != question:
        print('You spelled that word wrong, please try again!')
        answer = input('Retype the word and press enter:')
```

Comment: I added a nested while loop and now I can get it to confirm the right answer, but not generate another word.  I will try some of the purposed suggestions and get back to you all thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track, but as @guidot was saying you have to exit that loop, and you need a second loop to keep playing.
I would've written the code something like this:

```
def word_list(): 
    import random #Import random function
    words = ['hello',"yes","no","I","look","where","can","he","with","see","do","we","a","you","play","am","what","one","the","this","have","on","want","go","like","and","hurt","to","under","day","is","or","of","it","are","said","big","up","that","little","down","there","my","she","out","good","her","all","yes","make","read","no","they","your"]
    play = True
    # a first loop for the game, as it seemed that you wanted it "infinte"
    while play:
        # here starts a round, get a word
        question = random.choice(words) #Generates a random word from the list
        print(question) #Displays the word that was generated
        while True: # loop until the player types the word correctly
            answer = input('Retype the word and press enter: ') #User retypes the 
            if answer == question:
                # the player has answered correctly, award him
                print('Great job you spelled it correctly!')
                # check if the player wants to keep playing
                answer = input('Press enter for another word, write "exit" to stop: ')
                # if the answer was not exit, keep playing 
                play = answer.strip() != "exit"
                # this exit this loop, so it will end the round
                break
            else:
                # the answer was wrong 
                print('You spelled that word wrong, please try again!')
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for thank you for the advice!  I finally remembered about nested loops.  Does any one know of any free programs beside Visio to help me map out my code better?  thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 1):

`while True` starts an endless loop, so you have to take care, that it terminates.

The easiest solution is adding a `break` at the end of the `then` branch.

Comment: Where is the "then" branch again?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to need a solution that uses nested loops. One to get a word then an inner loop to get responses from the user until they get it right. I think a very light change to your code might allow you to do this:

```py
import random #Import random function

def word_list(): 
  words = ['hello',"yes","no","I","look","where","can","he","with","see","do","we","a","you","play","am","what","one","the","this","have","on","want","go","like","and","hurt","to","under","day","is","or","of","it","are","said","big","up","that","little","down","there","my","she","out","good","her","all","yes","make","read","no","they","your\n"]
  question = random.choice(list(words)) #Generates a random word from the list
  print(question) #Displays the word that was generated

  answer = input('Retype the word and press enter:') #User retypes the 
  while True: #Loop that allows user to 
    if answer == question: #If statement that confirms the user spelled the word right
      print('Great job you spelled it correctly!')
      input('Press enter for another word')
      return

    print('You spelled that word wrong, please try again!')
    answer = input('Retype the word and press enter:')

while True:
  word_list()
```

You might now look for a way to simplify this but this should get you going again.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little trick with loops. You don't need to have everything in them, only the stuff you want to repeat.

In this example, you don't want to put the main `input` in the loop, because that's not what you're repeat. What you are repeating is the part where you tell the user that they got it wrong and to input it again.

So what you want to do is to have the first `input` outside of the loop, and only put the retries inside.

```py
import random

words = ['hello',"yes","no","I","look","where","can","he","with","see","do","we","a","you","play","am","what","one","the","this","have","on","want","go","like","and","hurt","to","under","day","is","or","of","it","are","said","big","up","that","little","down","there","my","she","out","good","her","all","yes","make","read","no","they","your\n"]

def word_list(): 
  question = random.choice(list(words)) #Generates a random word from the list

  print(question) #Displays the word that was generated
  answer = input('Retype the word and press enter:') #User retypes the 

  while answer != question:  
    print('You spelled that word wrong, please try again!')
    answer = input('Retype the word and press enter:')

  print('Great job you spelled it correctly!')
```

The second part of your question means that you want another loop. In the interest of keeping the function simple, ideally you'd want this other loop to be wherever you called `word_list` rather than in `word_list` itself. It's good practice to keep each function limited to its purpose instead of trying to do everything in one function.

```py
while True:
  word_list()
  
  input('Press enter for another word')
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is in the while loop. I reorganized the code into functions to make it more readable.

```
def replay():

   return input('Play again Yes[Y] or N[N]')

def player_answer(question):

   answer = ''
   correct = False

while answer != question:
    answer = input('Retype the word and press enter:')

if answer == question:
        print('Great job you spelled it correctly!')
        correct = True

                
    
return correct
    

def word_list():
import random #Import random function
words = ['hello',"yes","no","I","look","where","can","he","with","see","do","we","a","you","play","am","what","one","the","this","have","on","want","go","like","and","hurt","to","under","day","is","or","of","it","are","said","big","up","that","little","down","there","my","she","out","good","her","all","yes","make","read","no","they","your\n"]
question = random.choice(list(words)) #Generates a random word from the list
print('Sorted word: ' + question)
return question #Displays the word that was generated


  game_on = True
  #lógica do game
  while True:


while game_on:
    
    question = word_list()
    answer = player_answer(question)
    
    if(answer):
        play_again = replay()
        if play_again == 'Y':
            question = word_list()
            answer = player_answer(question)
        else:
            print("Thanks for play!")
            game_on = False

break
```

make ur own adjustments

Answer (score 0):

You can add an exit word like "quit" and check for that to terminate the loop. Then, implement some more logic whether user wants to continue or quit when they get the right answer.

Also, keep the import statement outside of the function. Otherwise, it does a redundant import every time the function runs.

```
import random


def word_list():
    words = [
        "hello",
        "yes",
        "no",
        "I",
        "look",
        "where",
        "can",
        "he",
        "with",
        "see",
        "do",
        "we",
        "a",
        "you",
        "play",
        "am",
        "what",
        "one",
        "the",
        "this",
        "have",
        "on",
        "want",
        "go",
        "like",
        "and",
        "hurt",
        "to",
        "under",
        "day",
        "is",
        "or",
        "of",
        "it",
        "are",
        "said",
        "big",
        "up",
        "that",
        "little",
        "down",
        "there",
        "my",
        "she",
        "out",
        "good",
        "her",
        "all",
        "yes",
        "make",
        "read",
        "no",
        "they",
        "your",
    ]

    question = random.choice(list(words))  # Generates a random word from the list
    print(question)  # Displays the word that was generated
    answer = input("Retype the word and press enter:")  # User retypes the

    # Continue looping until user exits by typing "Quit"

    while answer.lower() != "quit":
        if answer == question:
            print("Great job you spelled it correctly!")

            answer = input('Press enter again for a new word or type "quit" to quit')
            
            
            if answer.lower() != "quit":
                question = random.choice(list(words))
                print(question)
                answer = input("Retype the word and press enter:")

        else:  # Has the user re-type the word if it was wrong
            print("You spelled that word wrong, please try again!")
            answer = input("Retype the word and press enter:")
```